# Is there anyway I can simplify my Python program? it runs but I feel like the implementation could be simpler

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program asks a user at a bank for 3 inputs their bank id number, first name, and last name. If the user input is not the same as the default user (Ryan) 
then, the user is blocked from continuing, else they are welcomed.

Can I have a simpler implementation for this

```
f_name = input("What is your first name: ") 
print("You entered:" + f_name)
f_name = f_name

l_name = input("What is your last name: ") 
print("You entered:" + l_name)
l_name = l_name

bid = int(input("What is your bid: "))
print(f"You entered: {bid}")
bid = bid

if f_name == "Ryan" and l_name == "Monaghan" and bid == 12345:
    print("Welcome, Ryan")
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```

Comment: Add the codes in the question rather than attaching an image

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You _specificallY_ should not do anything like `bid = bid` because it makes no sense.

Comment: I would say that you already have the **simplest** implementation. You don't need the extra var assignments as DYZ mentioned. You better hope the bidding site doesn't have a lot of customers though, because that'd be a lot of `if` statements to type out. And I have this vague feeling I can't put my finger on that the security model needs to be worked on a bit. =)

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of loops and comparison on data objects instead of values specifically.

```py
print('Please enter the following information:')
questions = [
    'First name',
    'Last name',
    'Bid'
]

answers = []

for q in questions:
    answers.append(input(q + ': '))

if answers == ['Ryan', 'Monaghan', '12345']:
    print('Welcome, Ryan')
else:
    print('Access Denied')
```

output:

```
Please enter the following information:
First name: Ryan
Last name: Monaghan
Bid: 12345
Welcome, Ryan
```

Comment: Thank you! :)   That certainly is a different and probably more effective approach that I am looking for

Comment: could you possible explain this line "answers.append(input(q + ': ')) "

Comment: we ask the question and append the input into the answers array.

Comment: @RyanMonahan I edited this answer .. is it clearer now..?

Comment: Got it thanks! and if i wanted to add a "Try again (y/n)" to the program how can I do that? Thanks :)

Comment: before answers = [] - while retry_answer != 'n': and after print('Welcome, Ryan') - break

Comment: Actually could you show it in the code. I seem to have some issues with compiling

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to a follow-up question as to how to provide a retry loop if the user input is rejected.

```py
print('Please enter the following information:')
questions = [
    'First name',
    'Last name',
    'Bid'
]

answers = []

while(True): # Loop indefinately
    for q in questions:
        answers.append(input(q + ': '))

    if answers == ['Ryan', 'Monaghan', '12345']:
        print('Welcome, Ryan')
        break # Got a valid response, break out of the loop, note you may want to set a variable here as well to denote a successful response.
    else:
        print('Access Denied')
        r = input('Would you like to retry? (y/n):').lower().strip()
        if r != 'y' and r != 'yes':
            break # user does not want to try again, break out of loop
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help!